# Pass numpy array to opencv function inputarray result in array changed

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I passed a binary image(mask) to `cv2.findContours()`， and I found that `mask` will change although it's an input parameter.

```py
    print('scale: [{} , {}]'.format(np.amin(mask),np.amax(mask)))
    contours = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    print('scale: [{} , {}]'.format(np.amin(mask),np.amax(mask)))
```

will output:

```
scale: [0,255]
scale: [0,130]
```

while:

```py
    print('scale: [{} , {}]'.format(np.amin(mask),np.amax(mask)))
    contours = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    print('scale: [{} , {}]'.format(np.amin(mask),np.amax(mask)))
```

will work, and prints

```
scale: [0， 255]
scale: [0， 255]
```

I guess it might be something like pass by reference, but I am not very good at python and quite unfamiliar with `python-opencv` bind. Could anyone tell me the reason?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior with opencv 4.1.2. Could you provide your opencv version ?

Comment: I guess you're using OpenCV older than 3.2, and did not read the documentation of `findContours` properly: "The function modifies the image while extracting the contours."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) is mentionned:

> Python: cv.FindContours(image, storage, mode=CV_RETR_LIST, method=CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, offset=(0, 0)) → contours
>   Parameters:
>   image – Source, an 8-bit single-channel image. Non-zero pixels are
>   treated as 1’s. Zero pixels remain 0’s, so the image is treated as
>   binary . You can use compare() , inRange() , threshold() ,
>   adaptiveThreshold() , Canny() , and others to create a binary image
>   out of a grayscale or color one. **The function modifies the image** while
>   extracting the contours. If mode equals to CV_RETR_CCOMP or
>   CV_RETR_FLOODFILL, the input can also be a 32-bit integer image of
>   labels (CV_32SC1).

Comment: yeah, I miss the statement. Thank you